# How can I specify multiple languages when sending a GET request to GitHub search API

Tags: github, github-api

I wonder how can I send a GET request to GitHub search API, specifically `https://api.github.com/search/repositories` and make the query to include several languages instead of one.

Here's my current query.

`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E=1000+language:scala&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10`

I have tried doing something like this but it didn't work as well

`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E=1000+language:[scala, java]&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in multiple `language:` element for being able to pass multiple languages to the query as per the [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-repositories#:%7E:text=you%20can%20also%20search%20for%20multiple%20topics%20by%20adding%20more%20topic:%20instances).

For your specific case, the query would be :

[`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E=1000+language:scala+language:java&sort=stars&order=desc`](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E=1000+language:scala+language:java&sort=stars&order=desc)

with pagination applied it would be :

[`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E=1000+language:scala+language:java&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10`](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:%3E=1000+language:scala+language:java&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10)

However, with pagination applied your search results will be limited in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it really helped. Also, I have read the documentation but couldn't really understand how to add those things together

Comment: been there. It just takes some getting used to the GitHub docs.